# ¿Cómo actualizar mediante tabla temporal en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta, pero me temo que el `INTO` no crea tablas temporales en *MySQL*, cosa que en *SQL server 2008 R2* sí lo hace sin problemas. Necesito actualizar una tabla a partir de los datos obtenidos de `sr_itemRock` para que se actualice en `sr_productos`. El detalle que no sale es la creación de tablas temporales.

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT a.ItemID, a.ItemDesc
INTO #Temp
from sr_itemrock a
INNER JOIN sr_productos b
on a.ItemID = b.codigo
WHERE id > 600

UPDATE sr_productos
SET 
 descripcion_bra IN (SELECT ItemDesc FROM #Temp)
,descripcion_eng IN (SELECT ItemDesc FROM #Temp)
,descripcion_esp IN (SELECT ItemDesc FROM #Temp)
WHERE
ItemID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM #Temp)

DROP Table #Temp
```

Esta consulta normalmente en *SQL Server* no tiene errores, pero en *MySQL* sí. El detalle está en las tablas temporales. ¿Alguien me da alguna idea de cómo actualizar datos de una tabla a otra usando tablas temporales?

**Error:**

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from sr_itemrock a
>   INNER JOIN sr_productos b
>   on a.ItemID = b.codigo
>   WHERE id ' at line 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siendo que tu pregunta parece centrarse en la primera consulta, mi respuesta se va a centrar en eso. Pero te menciono de paso que el `UPDATE` tampoco parece tener una sintaxis correcta para MySQL o SQL Server.

En efecto, la sintaxis `SELECT ... INTO ...` no funciona en MySQL. De hecho, la forma de crear tablas temporales también es diferente.

El equivalente a tu consulta de SQL Server:

```
SELECT a.ItemID, a.ItemDesc
INTO #Temp
from sr_itemrock a
INNER JOIN sr_productos b
on a.ItemID = b.codigo
WHERE id > 600
```

...sería la siguiente en MySQL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp AS
SELECT a.ItemID, a.ItemDesc
from sr_itemrock a
INNER JOIN sr_productos b
on a.ItemID = b.codigo
WHERE id > 600
```

Nota que la sintaxis es `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nombre AS SELECT ...`, y que el nombre que le asignas a la tabla no puede comenzar con un `#` como lo harías en SQL Server.

---

Para lo del `UPDATE`, la sintaxis en la claúsula `SET` no parece válido en cualquier motor de base de datos.

Sospecho que esta es la sentencia que buscas:

```
UPDATE sr_productos p
  JOIN Temp t
    ON t.ItemID = p.ItemID
   SET p.descripcion_bra = t.ItemDesc,
       p.descripcion_eng = t.ItemDesc,
       p.descripcion_esp = t.ItemDesc
```

Comment: Excelente y muy completa respuesta. Me parece además oportuno señalar que no es necesario dropear la tabla temporal, pues ésta morirá sola cuando se cierre la sesión.

Comment: @amenadiel: Gracias por mencionar ese punto, muy cierto.